# Installing pgrouting on macos

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgresql-extensions

I am struggling getting the pgrouting extension to Postgresql to work. I am running PG 13 and attempting to install pgrouting 3.3.0. The hos OS is Mac Monterey 12.0.1 (M1).

I have built pgrouting from source and all seems to go well. I had though to copy the extension control file manually and the so file. When I try to install the extension in PB ('create extension pgrouting cascade') I get:

**ERROR:  could not load library "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/lib/postgresql/libpgrouting-3.3.so": dlopen(/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/lib/postgresql/libpgrouting-3.3.so, 0x000A): tried: '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/lib/postgresql/libpgrouting-3.3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/libpgrouting-3.3.so' (no such file)
SQL state: 58P01**

Any clue to what is wrong?